# How to handle c# Element not available exception in AutomationElement

Tags: c#, winforms, automation

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetProcessById(element.Current.ProcessId);
```

Here Process is the windows process and element.Current.ProcessId is the automation element process Id (AutomationElement). It generates an error on running the application.How to handle this error.

Error Im getting is the following.

> An exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException' occurred in
>   UIAutomationClient.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native
>   boundary
>
> Additional information: The target element corresponds to UI that is
>   no longer available (for example, the parent window has closed).